# Powershell Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '*$var*'" Not working

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I looked around and couldn't find the reason this is happening and was looking for help or an explanation as to what is happening with this. This is powershell and active directory module

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*Doe*'"
```

Returns the correct object:

```
DistinguishedName : ############
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : John
Name              : John Doe
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : #############
SamAccountName    : JDoe
SID               : #############
Surname           : Doe
UserPrincipalName : John.Doe@Company.com
```

If i try to replace the hardcoded name with a variable while also using wildcards. The $manager variable is dynamically set from a csv, but even in this case of setting it like this. I'm runnning into issues

```
$Manager = "Doe"
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$Manager*'"
```

it returns nothing

When i paste in the string im using for the filter

```
Write-Host "Name -like '*$Manager*'"
```

Returns the correct format I did above in working query.
`Name -like '*Doe*'`

I would really appreciate some help on this as im not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Not sure what's happening there. Works fine when I try the exact same syntax.

Comment: Are you sure you're not reversing the order of the quotes? (first singles and then doubles)

Answer (score 3):

So I found the solution. Turns out I'm just an idiot. The "Doe" user was a placeholder, and the actual name being input was just mispelled, so of course it would never find anything. Thanks for the sanity check everyone... Mondays ...

Comment: Glad to hear this is solved. Since the solution is unlikely to benefit future readers, can I suggest you delete your post?